# How do I limit a sql account's access to one database?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server Express 2008 SP1 (10.0.2531) and would like to limit access for a SQL account to one database. I have the SQL account created. How do I grant this user access to the database but deny access to the others?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a USer.

1 - Using Security/logins. Add your user here (new login)

2 - User mapping

3 - users mapped to this login.

4- choose the DB that your user can access

Answer (score 0):

If you create a user in the security/logins node with the server role of public only they will not, by default, have access to any database.

Secondly, under the security/users node of the database base add themas a new user and then set the roles as required.

Finally, returning to the security/logins node you may want to change the default database to the specific one they are a user for.

Hope that helps